How does swagger "know" the ip of the host that it displays in UI?
I am using swagger with my .net core 6 project. I did all the usual configuration:
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen
app.UseSwagger
app.UseSwaggerUI

and swagger page with endpoints shows up, together with API name. There is a url of the swagger show underneath the name:
https://localhost:7089/swagger/v1/swagger.json

My question is:
How to access this url in Program.cs? I want to use it to show additional information in swagger page.
Thanks!

What kind of information do you want to add? For example, usage info typically goes into OpenApiInfo.Description, which can contain multi-paragraph Markdown-formatted text.

Specifically, I am adding a description where I show the document the user needs to download, adding a link "download documentation". I add it with url pointing to production site, but I would like it to be dynamic. So If I am running it in development the link is constructed out of local url. Swagger already "knows" this url, it shows in the UI : https://localhost:7089/swagger/v1/swagger.json. So instead of getting something from appsettings.json I am trying to extract it from somewhere in program.cs

The answer is:
var urls = builder.WebHost.GetSetting(WebHostDefaults.ServerUrlsKey);
